# Doctrine mapping error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mapping

When i try to import my mapping for my entity class like so ---

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force MyContentBundle yml
```

it always return me this error---

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                
  Property "countryid" in "GeonamesCountryinfo" was already declared, but it must be declared only once
```

[image]

do anyone knows how to solve this problem in symfony2.

Comment: Post definition of GeonamesCountryinfo entity

Comment: can you post your code where that GeonamesCountryinfo?